# ROS catkin_make executable is not generated in devel

Tags: executable, ros

I created a ROS package and added to the CMakeLists.txt the relevant lines to create an executable.

```
add_executable(exe_name src/file.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe_name $LIBRARIES)
```

When I run `catkin_make` in the root of the workspace the executable is generated in `WORKSPACE/build/PACKAGE_NAME/`
instead of in

```
WORKSPACE/devel/lib/PACKAGE_NAME/
```

The problem is now when I run `rosrun PACKAGE_NAME exe_name` the executable name (exe_name) is not found. Any ideas why this might happen?

### **Edit - added the complete CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(flea3ros)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
)
find_package(OpenCV 2)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /usr/include/flycapture
)
add_executable(flea3syncros src/asyncRos.cpp)
add_executable(flea3ros src/GigEGrabEx.cpp)
add_executable(flea3config src/GigEConfig.cpp)
add_executable(saveImages src/save_images.cpp)
target_link_libraries(flea3ros ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} flycapture)
target_link_libraries(flea3syncros ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} flycapture)
target_link_libraries(flea3config ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} flycapture)
target_link_libraries(saveImages  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: That's weird, I can't see anything wrong here. Have you tried to remove build/ and devel/ and then run `catkin_make` so that everything is generated new? (this has often solved catkin build problems for me)

Comment: Tried that, also didn't work. The weird thing is that other packages are created in the devel folder, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: So the problem is most likely somewhere within the package. Can you please provide the complete CMakeLists.txt of the package. Maybe the issue is hidden there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catkin_package` macro is missing in your CMakeLists.txt. Add this after the find_package section:

```
###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES compute_cdist
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp visualization_msgs robot_model_helper compute_cdist
#  DEPENDS assimp Eigen mlpack
)
```

(You can remove the comments of course, I just copied the whole block so that the description is contained)